# Table of clickable buttons - click a button unintentionally moves it down ...?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a code to to create a table style of buttons according to user input number of rows/cols.
After it creates the table, each button click, adds "X" or "O" text to it.

```js
var flag = "X";

var clicked = function() {
  if (this.innerHTML == "X" || this.innerHTML == "O") {
    alert("BUSY");
  } else if (this.innerHTML == "") {
    this.innerHTML = flag;
    if (flag == "X") {
      flag = "O"
    } else if (flag == "O") {
      flag = "X"
    }
  }
}

function createBoard() {
  var val = document.getElementById('nTabelInput').value;
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  box.innerHTML = " "; //empty outer div(box)

  for (var j = 1; j <= val; j++) {
    var lineDiv = document.createElement('div'); //create div for one line of btns
    box.appendChild(lineDiv); //append this line to outer div(box)

    for (var i = 1; i <= val; i++) {
      var oneBtnInLine = document.createElement('button'); //create one btn in line
      oneBtnInLine.className = "btn"; //use for design
      lineDiv.appendChild(oneBtnInLine); //append btn in the line
      oneBtnInLine.innerHTML = "";
      oneBtnInLine.addEventListener('click', clicked);
    }
  }
}

createBoard();
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffb2bf;
  border: 0;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span>Number of rows & columns: </span>
<input id="nTabelInput" value="3" style="width: 60px" min="3" type="number" onclick="createBoard()">
<div id="box"></div>
```

The problem is that each click changes the user interface so that the button pops down. It resets only after clicking the entire line.

Could you please help me figure why is it ?

and how to fix it (means the button doesn't move)?

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Your buttons pop because they start having no content, then you write something in them. You can constrain their proportions with `button { width:30px; height:30px; }` for instance

Comment: sorry, you are all much faster than me. I'v just added CSS. Now the question is done. please help !

Comment: Indeed, with CSS it changes the solution. Now try adding `vertical-align: top;` to your buttons.

Comment: @Jeremy Thille - You are the best!!! Give it as an answer and I'll green tick it.

Comment: Bah, I left this honor to another :) But you can also have a look at more robust solutions, like Flex or Grid (which are standard CSS features, not plug-ins or libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `vertical-align: bottom;` or `vertical-align: top;` then it will work perfectly!

Here's the code:

```js
var flag = "X";

var clicked = function() {
  if (this.innerHTML == "X" || this.innerHTML == "O") {
    alert("BUSY");
  } else if (this.innerHTML == "") {
    this.innerHTML = flag;
    if (flag == "X") {
      flag = "O"
    } else if (flag == "O") {
      flag = "X"
    }
  }
}

function createBoard() {
  var val = document.getElementById('nTabelInput').value;
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  box.innerHTML = " "; //empty outer div(box)

  for (var j = 1; j <= val; j++) {
    var lineDiv = document.createElement('div'); //create div for one line of btns
    box.appendChild(lineDiv); //append this line to outer div(box)

    for (var i = 1; i <= val; i++) {
      var oneBtnInLine = document.createElement('button'); //create one btn in line
      oneBtnInLine.className = "btn"; //use for design
      lineDiv.appendChild(oneBtnInLine); //append btn in the line
      oneBtnInLine.innerHTML = "";
      oneBtnInLine.addEventListener('click', clicked);
    }
  }
}

createBoard();
```

```css
  .btn {
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color: #ffb2bf;
        border: 0;
        margin: 1px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
   }
```

```html
<span>Number of rows & columns: </span>
<input id="nTabelInput" value="3" style="width: 60px" min="3" type="number" onclick="createBoard()">
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `button` elements by default (from the user agent stylesheet) have

```
vertical-align: baseline;
```

`baseline` refers to the contained text. If no text is contained, that results in a different `baseline` than the `button` has with text.

If you instead set a value for `vertical-align` which aligns the element independent of the `line`, you get the result you want. For example you can use `top`, `bottom` or `middle`.